# Reading File and storing into ArrayList

Tags: java

I have this FileIO class which reads a .txt file and stores them into a String ArrayList. However when i tried to print out the contents of my arrayList, it appears to be empty. Where have i made an error?

```
public class FileIO
{
    public ArrayList<String> readFile() throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            File file = new File("example.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                al.add(line);
            }
            fileReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(al.get(i));
        }

        return al;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileIO fileIO = new FileIO();
        ArrayList<String> temp = fileIO.readFile();      
    }
}
```

The contents of my txt file is just:

```
this is text1
this is text2
this is text3
```

Comment: Do you see any error or exception on console? I dont see any issue with above code unless you have empty file or file is not in classpath or file is empty.

Comment: Rather than attempt an answer, I'll try to "teach a man to fish". I suggest you read Eric Lipper's excellent 
[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), after which you'll probably know the answer to your question and, even better, be able to figure out answers to similar problems in the future.

Comment: @almasshaikh nope. no exceptions.

Comment: @BlairConrad thanks for the suggestion. Will add it into my to do lists.

Comment: @John use temo.size(); to find arraylist length it's not empty

Comment: The code works fine, and if you're not getting an exception it must be able to find the (or a) file, so presumably that file is empty.

Comment: @Boann Does this got to do anything with the symbol #? my text file actually contains #this is text1, but when i use the # symbol in the post it just consumes my # and enlarge the text behind.

Comment: @John You could answer that yourself by removing the # from the file. But no, it won't make a difference. So you must be reading the wrong file, or you're running the wrong code, or you're looking at a different panel in the IDE instead of the console output panel, or your computer has gone insane.

Comment: I've found another error. It does not throw an exception even after i remove the txt file from that same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason for not getting data is that you haven't set the file path correctly. And below line is not necessary for this.

File file = new File("example.txt");

You can directly create a FileReader object from the file name as below.

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("example.txt);